# Convert pinescript v2 to pinescript v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a simple strategy based on Pinescript v2. I would like to convert it to pinescript v5. Here is the v2 code:

```
//@version=2
strategy(title='Strategy 1', shorttitle='Strategy 1', overlay=true, pyramiding=0, initial_capital=10, currency=currency.USD)
trade_size = input(1)
tf = input('60')
r = heikenashi(tickerid)
ro = security(r, tf, open)
rc = security(r, tf, close)
sel_entry = crossunder(rc, ro)
buy_entry = crossover(rc, ro)
strategy.entry('sell', long=strategy.short, qty=trade_size, comment='sell', when=sel_entry)
strategy.entry('buy', long=strategy.long, qty=trade_size, comment='buy', when=buy_entry)
```

What I have managed to do so far:

```
//@version=5
strategy(title='v5', shorttitle='v5', overlay=true, pyramiding=0, initial_capital=10, currency=currency.USD)
trade_size = input.int(1)
tf = input.timeframe('60')
ha_ticker = ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid)
ha_open = request.security(ha_ticker, tf, open)
ha_close = request.security(ha_ticker, tf, close)
sel_entry = ta.crossunder(ha_close, ha_open)
buy_entry = ta.crossover(ha_close, ha_open)
strategy.entry('sell', strategy.short, qty=trade_size, comment='sell', when=sel_entry)
strategy.entry('buy', strategy.long, qty=trade_size, comment='buy', when=buy_entry)
```

**The problem is that it doesn't work properly.**

Results in Pinescript v2:

[Pinescript v2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHHMM.png)

Results in Pinescript v5:

[Pinescript v5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cKB0.png)

I tried many solutions, but always the results are completely different than in pinescript v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some big changes from `v2` to `v5`. The most important change you need to know in your case is [default behaviour of security function has changed](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/To_Pine_version_3.html#default-behaviour-of-security-function-has-changed).

This causes the difference in reults. If you wish to have the same results, you should be using `barmerge.lookahead_on`. However, by doing so you will be using future data which is not recommended. More info [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#understanding-lookahead).

Answer (score 0):

```
haClose = (open + high + low + close) / 4
haOpen  = float(na)
haOpen := na(haOpen[1]) ? (open + close) / 2 : (nz(haOpen[1]) + nz(haClose[1])) / 2
haHigh  = max(high, max(haOpen, haClose))
haLow   = min(low, min(haOpen, haClose))
```

use the above formula to calculate HA OHLC, and then use them upon barclosure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).